# C# Cut Copy Paste and working with a Class

Tags: c#

Currently doing a wee project and been asked if i can include cut copy paste functions.

Wondering the easiest way to do this going forward.

It is multiple textboxes, a location and a listview.

At the moment i have it copying out a large string but can not get a paste to work.

Wondering if their is an easier way to perform this?

Comment: What and where are you needing to copy and paste? Typically, textboxes will support copy and paste by default.  Are you needing to paste into/out of the listviews?

Comment: Could you clarify if this is `XAML` related or `WinForms` related please? Just having the `C#` is  bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the clipboard using the `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` class (or `System.Windows.Clipboard` for WPF) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx

For example, you can get the text stored in the clipboard by using the `GetText()` method, or you can store a text using the `SetText()` method.